# boost::type_erasure basic example doesn't build

Tags: c++, boost, type-erasure

I am testing the new `boost::type_erasure`. Unfortunately taking the code of the basic example as it is it doesn't build. To be more specific this [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/type_erasure/example/basic.cpp) the function `basic2()` is giving trouble. I tried to highlight who is creating the issues and it seems that these 2 concepts are the cause

```
incrementable<>  // error: no match for ‘operator++’ in ‘++arg’
ostreamable<>   // error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘out << arg
```

If I am not wrong these are 2 concepts are already implemented in the library; being used with `int` the code should really work as it is so I don't know how to fix this issue.

Has any of you guys  had a similar issue and in case do you have any idea about how to fix it?

I am using `gcc 4.4.7-3`

I also tried the following example

```
class CTest{
public:
CTest(const CTest& o){}
CTest(){}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const CTest& obj){
    return o;
}

void basic2() {        
    CTest c;           
    any<
        mpl::vector<
            copy_constructible<>,
            typeid_<>,
            ostreamable<>
        >
    >  x(c);

    std::cout << c ;
}
```

And I have the same error. It actually points to this code in boost saying that

```
 error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘out << arg’
```

Below is the function that fails. I don't understand why as it needs `operator<<` that is already defined.

```
    // from operators.hpp from boost type_erasure
    /**
     * The @ref ostreamable concept allows an @ref any to be
     * written to a @c std::ostream.
     */
    template<class Os = std::ostream, class T = _self>
    struct ostreamable
    {
        static void apply(Os& out, const T& arg) { out << arg; }
    };
```

Comment: I can't see any `iostreamable<>` in the example you linked. Maybe provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I meant ostreamable<>. I edited the post.

Comment: From the source you linked and the commentary you probably meant `incrementable<>`

Comment: ..still slow this morning..thanks for the spot.Post edited.

Comment: The code works fine on g++ 4.8.1. If you look [here](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/release/developer/type_erasure.html) in the note on g++ 4.4 and below it says that " This compiler's bugs are not supported by the library.".

Comment: Alright...this ends my hopes! I need to update. Thanks a lot!